# Backtracking function - Show only the words that starts and ends with the letter a

Tags: c++, backtrace

I am currently a high school student and a beginner at programming on C++ and LUA.
I am trying to make a program using CodeBlocks, and I just made this code on C++:

```
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int st[20],n,ok,x,p;
char v[8] = "abcdefg",voc[] = "aeiouAEIOU",lit[] = "a";
// (n - 1)! n=9

void afisare(int k){
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=k;i++)
        cout<<v[st[i]]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

void valid(int k,int&ok){
    int i;
    ok = 0;
    //cout<<v[st[k]];
    if (strchr(lit,v[st[1]]) != NULL && strchr(lit,v[st[k]]) != NULL)
        ok = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= k-1; i++)
        if (st[k] == st[i])
            ok = 0;

}

void back(){
    int k;
    k = 1;
    x = 0;
    st[k] = -1;
    while(k > 0){
        ok = 0;
        while (ok==0 && st[k]<n - 1){
            st[k] = st[k] + 1;
            valid(k,ok);
        }
        if (ok == 1)
            if (k == n){ //
                afisare(k);
                x++;
                }
            else {
                k++;
                st[k] = -1;}
        else
            k--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //cin>>p;
    n = strlen(v);
    //while (p > n)
        //cin>>p;
    back();
    cout<<endl<<"x! = "<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

However it only shows:

```
x! = 0
```

Does anyone know the solution for this program? I am currently beginner at backtracking by the way.

Comment: Hi there! Congratulations on trying to learn C++. Do you know how to use your debugger in CodeBlocks? Using your debugger is an essential skill for a programmer. It allows you to step through the program, line-by-line, and inspect the values of all of your variables after each line. If you learn how to use your debugger, problems like this will be a thing of the past for you.

Comment: Look at what you do with `x` in `back()`.

Comment: Since you are just starting out, here's a tip: Use descriptive names. Variable names like `k` and `x` are _usually_ to be avoided. Also, a few comments here and there would help others read your code.